# FPDI-2.3.6 "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "FPDI" not found" (2021)

Tags: fpdf, fpdi

I download and uncompress `FPDF 1.83` and `FPDI 2.3.6`, after I load correctlly  with:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf183/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDI-2.3.6/src/autoload.php');
```

but when I try use:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf183/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDI-2.3.6/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();
```

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "FPDI" not found ... on line 5`

how I can fixed that?, how I can use ALL functions FPDI and FPDF without use `composer` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need use additional line: `use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;`

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf183/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDI-2.3.6/src/autoload.php');
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
```

However opening PDFs with PDFI in `2021` maybe you get:

`Alternatively the document you're trying to import has to be resaved without the use of compressed cross-reference streams and objects by an external programm (e.g. by lowering the PDF version to 1.4).`

Then setasign.com reply: `We offer a commercial addon which enables FPDI to handle documents that uses these compression features.` :@

https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/error-document-compression-technique-not-supported/

Comment: yes!, in 2021 I get `Fatal error: Uncaught setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReferenceException: This PDF document probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.` sone solution?